# MP3 player with good podcast support?

Tags: hardware, mp3-player, podcast

By good podcast support I mean:

- resuming the audio files where I
  switched off the player or skipped
  the file.
- Synching with my podcatcher
  (currently I'm using Miro but I could
  change): deleting episodes, I
  listened to and copy new ones from my
  HDD to the player.
- A wifi capable player would be great since I wouldn't need to switch on the computer but this is not mandatory.

I also have an additional condition: The player should not be manufactured by Apple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a ***Sandisk Sansa Clip***, which can be used in [MSC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_mass_storage_device_class)- or [MTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol)-Mode. It plays ogg files and can resume podcasts.

It is recognized well with ubuntu/banshee.

The only problem is, that the player's podcast folder is outside the music folder. But banshee stores podcasts in music/podcasts. So the player doesn't recognize all podcasts as podcast. The unrecognized files are treated as music and resume after you switch the player off, but doesn't remember the last position, when skipping the file.

When using the player with banshee, you have to manually define which episodes you heard with the player after that it automatically synchronizes your new episodes and removes the old ones.

Comment: Also, the Clip+ has a Micro SD slot.

Comment: I have a Clip+, and I just put my podcasts into the Podcast folder and haven't had any troubles. (When you start a podcast, it asks if you want to resume where you last left off, or at the beginning.) - Whoops, I missed the bit about synching with the Podcatcher. I prefer to copy and delete the files myself, so I don't know what kind of synching job it does.

Comment: It can also play flac files but I think upgrading the firmware is necessary. That's simply a matter of placing the update on the root of the filesystem. I found the UI to be a nightmare but otherwise it's ok. Beware mtp support can be difficult in Ubuntu.

Comment: The alternative open-source firmware [Rockbox](http://www.rockbox.org) solves the ui issues and adds a bunch of new features.

Comment: I've been using the Sansa Clip+ for a while now and I have to say: it was a good choice.

I'm using gPodder to download and sync the podcasts. After I listened to an episode, I delete it on the player. gPodder has a "delete podcasts you listened to on the player" function but this deletes every episode you started listening to, not only the ones you completed.

I sorted out the problems I had with ID3 tags by rewriting all tags by gPodder after download.

UI could be a bit better. For instance, "podcasts" is a submenu of "music" which I wouldn't expect and which doesn't make to much sense.

Comment: I also had problems with the player deleting a wrong episode (of the same podcast). I couldn't really find out, when exactly this happens but I learned how to avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

A rather savvy Linux developer recommended [Cowon](http://www.cowonglobal.com/) to my lady, and she's been quite happy with it...

Comment: I had a cowon iAudio 7 that I liked just fine, but after ~2 years it just bricked up on me, which is a big bummer.